# mongodb search on single key of document

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb document with data as following :

```
[{
  "name": "Robin singh",
  "developer": "java",
  "address": "Robin Singh,Mohali",
  "search_string": ["Robin", "Singh", "java"]
}, {
  "name": "Rohan singh",
  "developer": "java",
 "address": "Rohan Singh,Mohali",
  "search_string": ["Rohan", "Singh", "java"]
}]
```

I want to search document with developer **java** with name **Rohan singh** and I used this query:

`{"search_string":{"$all":["Robin","Singh","java"]}}`

but I am getting both results.

Comment: If you know `name`  and `developer` value then why you not used them in find?

Comment: I am very confused by your question.

Comment: `{"name":"Rohan singh", "developer":"java", "search_string":{"$all":["Robin","Singh","java"]}}` so like that?

Comment: Your search_string is identical in both your example docs... if this is how it is in your database, that explains your problem

Comment: Here you are using only `search_string` which is same in both documents. so it gives same result

Comment: oh..that's by mistake... actually this is just a short example I have created to explain...I have large documents and my search criteria returns the records matching java and with whatever the name is in other reference like - if address contains robin it will also return that

Comment: Still your question is pretty unclear. Your sample data is also confusing. can you please provide more sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.testcollection.aggregate([
    { $match: {"search_string":{"$all":["Robin","Singh","java"]}} },
    { $group: { _id: "$name"} }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `name` and `developer` then you can simply use find query -

```
db.collection.find({"name":"Rohan singh", "developer":"java"})
```

Additionally, If you want to check when `search_string` contains exact parameters which you are passing in `$all` then -  You need to use combination of [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) and [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to get desired result. size must be the number of parameters that you are using in $all. Here you must check size of `search_string` to number of params in $all so that it will search given parameters ($all) only in those `search_string` which size matches to number of params.

Following query might be helpful to you.

```
db.collection.find({
"name":"Rohan singh",
"search_string": {
  $all: ["Rohan", "singh","java"]
},
"search_string": {
$size: 3 // This is the number of param you pass in $all
}
}).pretty()
```